# How to edit a single columns results Tidying pandas dataframe results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I've just recently written my first web scraper to gather data on price fluxuations across websites

when webscraping this page the results i get on 'price' seem to come back as double and i would like to edit the results printed in the database as to make them a bit more legible at a glance.

```
def getproducts(itemlink):
    URL = f"https://www.XXXX.com/{itemlink}"
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, verify=certifi.where())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


    products = soup.find_all('main', {'class': 'main-content'})

    for item in products:
        product = {
        'product_title': item.find('h1', {'class': 'product-single__title'}).text.replace('\n', ''),
        'price': (item.find('span', {'class': 'product__price'}).text.replace('\n', '')),
        }

        productlist.append(product)
    return

getproducts('XXXXXXLINKXXXXX')


df = pd.DataFrame(data=productlist, columns= ['product_title', 'price'])

df = df.dropna(thresh=1, subset=['price'])

df = df.reset_index(drop = True)

print(df)
```

*results look like this*

product_title          price       
0        ITEM X  £34895£348.95

*but i'd like them to look like this:*

product_title          price.      
0        ITEM X  £348.95

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a JSON array you may have a look on [pd.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Using your code above could look like this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(productlist)
```

The keys you specify when scraping your website will be your column name. Each value item inside the JSON array will be a separate row.

**UPDATE**

based on your comment, there are multiple ways to do so:

1. inside the for item in products loop: before you create the JSON object and append it to your list you could do something like:

```
for item in products:
    price = str(item.find('span', {'class': 'product__price'}).text.replace('\n', ''))[-6:]
    product = {
        'product_title': item.find('h1', {'class': 'product-single__title'}).text.replace('\n', ''),
        'price': price,
    }

    productlist.append(product)
```

2. after you have built your JSON list:

```
for item in productlist:
    item["price"] = item["price"][-6:]

# build your DataFrame
```

3. using [lambda function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) after you have build your panda's DataFrame:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(productlist)

df = df.dropna(thresh=1, subset=['price'])

df = df.reset_index(drop = True)

df["price"] = df["price"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-6:])

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however adding that into my code hasn't seemed to change anything. I'm still getting the exact same result, I believe the key 'price' is scraping the entire text content in that <span> tag and so i'm looking for a way to add in a .str[-6:] somewhere i just dont know where